# How can I find an error formula for density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

$${p} = \frac{4m}{πtd^2}$$

How can I find the error in this formula? I don't know where to begin. I know that I'm looking for the "partial derivative" of density to solve this, but that is a brand new concept for me, which I don't fully understand.

$$p=density$$
$$ m=mass$$ 
$$t=thickness$$

$$ d=diameter$$

Comment: BTW density is supposed to be the Greek letter $\rho$ (rho), not $p$.

Comment: A [partial derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) of a multivariable function with respect to one of the variables it depends on is just the ordinary derivative if you assume all the other variables are constants.  So for your $p=\frac {4m}{\pi td^2}$ you have $\frac {\partial p}{\partial d}=\frac {-8m}{\pi td^3}$ by the power rule.  I suggest you read the Wikipedia page I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function $f$ of variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots$. If you assume your input quantities' errors are uncorrelated, then the variance of the output is given by the standard [error propagation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification)
$$ \sigma_f^2 = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\right)^2 \sigma_{x_1}^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\right)^2 \sigma_{x_2}^2 + \ldots. $$

I gave a more direct proof of this [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/59634), using just basic probability and no linear algebra. You should read through and understand some proof or another -- there is no reason to just take this formula on faith.