# Uncertainty propagation upon taking the median

Tags: error-analysis, metrology

If I have $N$ repeated occurrences of a measurement $x$ with uncorrelated errors and identical uncertainties $u_x$, and take the mean $\langle x\rangle$, the uncertainty on the mean becomes:

$$u_{\langle x\rangle} = \frac{u_x}{\sqrt{N}}$$

where $N$ is the number of measurements I have taken.  This is derived from the law of propagation of uncertainties (for example, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/217964/6319)).

If I take the median instead of the mean, I'm mathematically only propagating information from one or two data points, which would mean $N=1$ or $N=2$.  But that seems unfair, for surely the principle should hold that if I repeat the measurement many times and take the median, the resulting uncertainty goes down.

Is there any established way of propagating the uncertainty when taking the median of a series of measurements?

Comment: Related but different question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/47738/12615

Comment: There is a significant section about this on wikipedia. Did you look there? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#The_sample_median

Comment: @RobJeffries That appears to address on how to estimate an uncertainty based on the median, not how an already-estimated uncertainty propagates upon the calculation of the median, unless I misunderstand it.  I'm not asking about how to estimate anything based on the spread of my data.

Comment: I don't follow. Your question asks how to calculate an uncertainty in a median value given a set of measurements that define the median. The straightforward answer is that it depends on the underlying properties of the population and there is no trivial solution.

Comment: @RobJeffries No, I'm not asking how to estimate/calculate the uncertainty, I'm asking how to *propagate* an uncertainty when calculating the median, assuming uncorrelated errors and identical uncertainties for each measurement (which is of course a calculation, but a different one).  I already have an estimate for the uncertainty on each of my $N$ measurements.  When I take the mean, this simply propagates as $\sqrt{N}$ from the [law of propagation of uncertainties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification).  The question is what happens in case of the median.

Comment: That is not how your question reads. You are asking (in plain black and white) what the uncertainty is on the median when you take lots of measurements.

Comment: @RobJeffries I have edited the question but I was explicitly asking about *propagation* from the start, including the title and including the relevant formula.  Either way, I hope the question is clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think you are estimating the uncertainty of your median correctly.

The ratio of the variance of the mean to the variance of the median is given by $4n/[\pi(2n+1)]$, where $N=(2n+1)$ is the total number of data points in the sample you have used to construct the median. I think this approximation is only true if your outliers are symmetric.

Thus the uncertainty in the median is given by
$$ \Delta x_{Med} = \Delta \bar{x} \sqrt{\pi(2n+1)/4n},$$

In the limit of large $N$ (and hence large $n$), this tends to
$$ \Delta x_{Med} = \Delta \bar{x} \sqrt{\pi/2},$$

The uncertainty in the mean $\Delta \bar{x}$ is the standard deviation of the points divided by $\sqrt{N}$ and therefore the precision of your estimate will improve as $\sqrt{N}$.

This information is given at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StatisticalMedian.html

If you have outliers, then the formula that you begin your question with is *incorrect* (see the first sentence of the [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/217964/6319) you refer to). The data points will not be normally distributed according to your estimate of their uncertainties and the standard error of the mean that I quote above will be larger than $u_x/\sqrt{N}$ because the standard deviation of the data will be larger than $u_x$ (I refer you also to the last paragraph of *my* answer to that question).

Comment: I did have an incorrect estimate of my uncertainty (but for a different reason).