# Error propagation estimation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis, statistics

I have a physical quantity A defined as $A=(74.5 B^2*(M+N))^{1/3}$

where B, M, N and relative uncertainties are given. And M and N are dependent on B:

$log M=(0.755 \pm 0.059)*log B+(0.416\pm 0.024)$

$log N=(0.352 \pm 0.166)*log B-(0.262\pm 0.067)$

This two relations are the results of fitting a lot of data and it is assumed that the error on M, N is 15%.

The value of B is given by a software, and it is known with uncertainty 0.0002.

I need to know how this uncertainties affect the value of A. Can I use the fomula reported in the paragraph "Simplification" in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty)?

Comment: do you know the dependence of M and N on B or is it required in general terms?

Comment: @Numrok yes, I know them. For example, $log M=(0.755 \pm 0.059)*log B+(0.416\pm 0.024)$. The value of B is given by a software and its error is 0.0002. Using the fomulas, I get M and N. It is assumed that the error on M and N is 15%. I'd like to know how the error on B affect the value of A.

Comment: that information all needs to be in the question for an answer to be possible. Could you edit it such that all the information necessary is contained?

Comment: @Numrok Question edited. Please, let me know if you need other details. Many thanks

Comment: Is B a constant or does it vary over some range? Approximate value(s)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why propagation of uncertainty is linear?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59628/why-propagation-of-uncertainty-is-linear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **ANSWER 1**

You're asking about [*error propagation*](http://www.rit.edu/~w-uphysi/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html). In your case:

$\sigma_{M+N} = \sqrt{\sigma_M^2 + \sigma_N^2}$

$3\dfrac{\sigma_A}{A} = \sqrt{2(\dfrac{\sigma_B}{b})^2 + (\dfrac{\sigma_{M+N}}{M+N})^2} $

The wrinkle in my calculation is that I assume that the errors in B, M and N are independent. Since M and N are functions of B that isn't strictly true.

*(I asked in a comment on the question for more information on B - don't know if that information will be shared or not.)*

### **ANSWER 2**

You could calculate the error experimentally. Generate the appropriate random errors for each value assuming the normal distribution and calculate values for A 1000 times. Then calculate the mean and std dev of A.

Gaussian errors are calculated by using a random number between 0 and 1, then using the CDF of the normal distribution to do a reverse lookup of the std dev.

Comment: Could you explain me how you have obtained the second results? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was brain dead. I've fixed the second one. For addition and subtraction you use the sqrt of the squares of the individual standard deviations. For multiplication and division you use the sqrt of the squares of the relative standard deviations. $B^2$ = B*B

Comment: why did you have obtained $3 \sigma_A/A?$ what's the difference with this formula? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification many thanks

Comment: reformulate your equations as $A^3=(74.5 B^2*(M+N))$ so the left side is $\text{A*A*A}$

Comment: The wrinkle in my calculation is that I assume that the errors in B, M and N are independent. Since M and N are functions of B that isn't strictly true.

Comment: That B, M and N are not independent is surely the whole point of the question?