# Want to prove a differentiation based formula for propagated uncertainty

Tags: differentiation, error-analysis

I recently learned of the concept of propagated uncertainty, and I was introduced to the rule that
if $$ X = AB$$
then if $A$ has an uncertainty of $\Delta A$ and $B$ has an uncertainty of $\Delta B$, the uncertainty of $X$ can be found using the formula
$$\frac{\Delta X}{X} = \frac{\Delta A}{A} + \frac{\Delta B}{B}$$

I've been told that this is somewhat based off differentiation; I want to know the logic behind this. Could anyone please help me understand how they came to this formula? It's not very intuitive.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59628/50583 and its linked questions

Comment: Differentiation-based argument: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/772871/226902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For X = AB

$\frac{dX}{dB}=A$ ... this is the rate of change of X when A varies infintesimally

$\frac{dX}{dA}=B$ ... this is the rate of change of X when B varies infintesimally

thus, given the two errors $\Delta A$ and $\Delta B$ and , we can determine the approximate variation in X. (Smaller errors will make this more accurate.)

$\Delta X = \frac{dX}{dA} \Delta A  +  \frac{dX}{dB} \Delta B$

(aside: the term in $\Delta A \Delta B$ is small and has been omitted.)

$$\boxed{\Delta X = B\Delta A + A\Delta B }$$

The above is the equation I use. Division by AB (noting AB=X) gives a slightly more memorable version,

$\frac{\Delta X}{X} = \frac{\Delta A}{A} + \frac{\Delta B}{B} $

This can be visualised using the example of calculation of area for a rectangle.
[image: ![Error in Product Visualised]

Answer (score 0):

@JMLCarter's answer is what would be expected of you at your academic level, I guess, but I have to warn you that your formula is actually incorrect if you are serious about probability and statistics.

Why probability and statistics, you may ask? Because in a lot of practical applications, $A$ does actually not represent a single value but a random distribution of values, what you would get by repeated measurements. You can then define a mean value $\newcommand{EE}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle} \EE{A}$ and we also need to define how the values are spread about that mean value, which will give us a way to measure the uncertainty. This is done by looking at the mean value of the square of the differences to the mean: $V(A)=\EE{(A-\EE{A})^2}$, a quantity called the variance of $A$. Then the uncertainty you seek is just the square root of the variance: $\sigma_A = \sqrt{V(A)}$, or conversely the variance is the square of that uncertainty. So your $\Delta A$ is my $\sigma_A$, etc. $\sigma_A$ is called the standard uncertainty of $A$ by the way. We define similar quantities for $B$ and $X$.

I will assume a very important condition: that $A$ and $B$ are independent, i.e. that whatever is the source of error for one does not influence the other. This has an important consequence: the mean of $AB$ is just the product of the means (i.e. there is no "interference" between $A$ and $B$), or mathematically.

$$\EE{AB}=\EE{A}\EE{B}.$$

Thus the variance reads

$$V(AB) = \EE{(AB-\EE{AB})^2}=\EE{(AB-\EE{A}\EE{B})^2}.$$

Then, we have the awesome trick:

$$AB - \EE{A}\EE{B} = \EE{A}\EE{B}\left[\left(\underbrace{\frac{A-\EE{A}}{\EE{A}}}_{\displaystyle\delta_A}+1\right)\left(\underbrace{\frac{B-\EE{B}}{\EE{B}}}_{\displaystyle\delta_B}+1\right)-1\right]
=\EE{A}\EE{B}\left[\delta_A + \delta_B + \delta_A\delta_B\right]. \tag{I}
$$

We will then assume that $\delta_A$ and $\delta_B$ are small. Such a statement makes sense since their mean values is 0. We can therefore allow ourselves to neglect the term $\delta_A\delta_B$. We square:

$$(AB - \EE{A}\EE{B})^2=\EE{A}^2\EE{B}^2(\delta_A^2+\delta_B^2 + 2\delta_A\delta_B)$$

and take the mean,

$$V(AB)=\EE{A}^2\EE{B}^2\left(\frac{V(A)}{\EE{A}^2}+\frac{V(B)}{\EE{B}^2}\right),$$

exploiting the fact that $\delta_A$ and $\delta_B$ are independent since $A$ and $B$ are so, and therefore that $\EE{\delta_A\delta_B}=\EE{\delta_A}\EE{\delta_B}=0$.

Finally, we get

$$\frac{\sigma_X}{\EE{X}} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\sigma_A}{\EE{A}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sigma_B}{\EE{B}}\right)^2}\tag{II}$$

This is actually the correct formula as per the laws of statistics. So how much does it differ from your naive formula? You can see it on the following diagram.

[image]

You are basically replacing Pythgoras theorem with: *the hypothenuses is the sum of the two other sides*. Well, we have the triangular identity

$$\frac{\sigma_X}{\EE{X}} \le \frac{\sigma_A}{\EE{A}} + \frac{\sigma_B}{\EE{B}}$$

So at least the naive formula gives an upper bound: you find an uncertainty for $X$ which is guaranteed to be bigger than the correct one, which is fortunate!

Addendum: since the question was marked as a duplicate, I should at least try to add to the previous answer. We can compute $\sigma_X$ exactly without neglecting anything. Let's restart from eqn (I): we square without neglecting anything and get

$$(AB - \EE{A}\EE{B})^2=\EE{A}^2\EE{B}^2\big(\delta_A^2+\delta_B^2 + 2\delta_A\delta_B + 2\delta_A^2\delta_B + 2\delta_A\delta_B^2+\delta_A^2\delta_B^2\big)$$

and then take the mean value, using the fact that $\delta_A$ and $\delta_B$ are independent,

$$\sigma_X^2 = \EE{A}^2\EE{B}^2\big(\EE{\delta_A^2}+\EE{\delta_B^2} + 2\underbrace{\EE{\delta_A}}_0\EE{\delta_B} + 2\EE{\delta_A^2}\underbrace{\EE{\delta_B}}_0 + 2\underbrace{\EE{\delta_A}}_0\EE{\delta_B^2}+\EE{\delta_A^2}\EE{\delta_B^2}\big).$$

Thus we finally get

$$\frac{\sigma_X}{\EE{X}} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\sigma_A}{\EE{A}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sigma_B}{\EE{B}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sigma_A\sigma_B}{\EE{A}\EE{B}}\right)^2}$$

thus adding a corrective term to the previous eqn. (II). And that is the fully correct formula without any approximation whatsoever.

Comment: Can you fix/explain $(\delta_A + \delta_B)^2 \neq \delta_A^2+\delta_B^2+2\delta_A\delta_B$ between 4th and 5th equations? The first neglection was fine, but in this step the 3rd term could be significant.

Comment: You are correct: I slipped there…

Comment: It seems wong that the property of independence of A and B implies AB=0? 
Clearly doesn't work for a trivial rectangle area calculation.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(disambiguation)

Comment: It's $\delta_A$ and $\delta_B$. Each have a zero mean.

Comment: Actually, I hadn't noticed the question was a duplicate. My answer agrees with [the more general one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/59634/154997).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment on the answers given by @JMLCarter and @LucJ.Bourhis rather than an answer.

> $A$ has an uncertainty of $\Delta A$ and $B$ has an uncertainty of $\Delta B$

in its simplest interpretation means that the actual value of $A$ is somewhere between $A+\Delta A$ and $A-\Delta A$ and that the actual value of $B$ is somewhere between $B+\Delta B$ and $B-\Delta B$

So the maximum value of $AB$ is $(A+\Delta A)(B+\Delta B) = AB + A\Delta B + B\Delta A+ \Delta A \Delta B$

So the maximum fractional error in $AB$ is given by $\dfrac {\Delta (AB)}{AB} = \dfrac{\Delta A}{A} + \dfrac {\Delta B}{B}+ \dfrac{\Delta A \Delta B}{AB}$

If $\Delta A$ and $\Delta B$ are small then $\Delta A \Delta B$ (a second order term) will be very small and so can be neglected.
This is the sort of procedure used in calculus to find a differential from first principles.

---

The @JMLCarter error is a sort of maximum error in that the error in $AB$ is calculated from the spread of possible values of $AB$ from when $A$ and $B$ are both a maximum ($A+\Delta A$ and $B+\Delta B$) at the same time to when $A$ and $B$ are both a minimum  ($A+\Delta A$ and $B+\Delta B$) at the same time.

---

The @LucJ.Bourhis error, which is smaller than the @JMLCarter error, is worked out on the assumption that having the errors in both $A$ and $B$ at a maximum (or a minimum) at the same time are not very likely events.
For example the errors could be in opposite directions ($A+\Delta A$ and $B-\Delta B$ or $A-\Delta A$ and $B+\Delta B$) and it is much more likely that the errors are smaller than $\Delta A$ and $\Delta B$.
So the chances of the fractional error in $AB$ being the sum of the fractional errors in $A$ and $B$ is small.

A better estimator of the error in $AB$, and hence the likelihood of the actual value of $AB$ being between $AB +\,\rm error$ and $AB - \,\rm error$, is found by evaluating the square root of the squares of the fraction errors in $A$ and $B$ which will give the fractional error in $AB$.

Comment: In the example of area calculation (as per diagram in my answer), the root sum of the squared errors has dimensions of length, not of area. i.e. it fails dimensional analysis.